# Remove access to the printer in terminal server

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, network-printer

I got a task where i need to remove printer access for specific users only when accessing the terminal server. It is a network printer from another site that we added on our server. Users uses the terminal server for their application and printer access in different sites.

Comment: It's a local pritner added on the TS ? filter the security on it

Comment: Its a network printer

Comment: Network printer is not the relevant part. Is it added as a printer on the Terminal Server, or is it added from a shared printer that is on another machine? In other words, if your Terminal Server is the print server, you can just limit access through security ACL.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect this network printer using [LPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol) or [IPP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) then printer is "local" in windows terminology, and you can setup ACL for it (in it's properties "Security" tab).

If your network printer is localy connected to other Windows host [you can share it with LPD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2665700) and then connect to you terminal server wia LPD and get ability to set ACL.

If you connect your network printer wia SMB - there no way to set any ACL on host where printer connected (In Windows terminology is a network printer, and "Security" tab not available in it's properties). You can setup ACL only on host which share printer.